# How to install wireless access point EDUP EP-2906?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ip-address, static-ip

I 'm trying to install wireless access point device EP-2906, on my Desktop PC running Windows 7. Here is the 
[installation guide](http://www.ncomputer.net/download/ap2906/ep2906-user-manual.pdf).

Page 7 says how I can set up it's IP address, but I can't find *Wireless Network Connection* icon. Is this because of my Desktop PC and in this case how can I set up a static private IP address for this device?

Comment: Does your PC have a wireless device?

Comment: @Ramhound My PC doesn't have any wireless device (except router). I thought EP-2906 plays this role.

Comment: Okay, the "guide" is not very helpful. The device looks like it can be an access point or a usb wifi adapter selected by a switch. in the latter case it should install drivers and show up among your network adapters i would guess. Maybe try to find a driver package for it.

Comment: @dempap - I was under the impression it was an access point not an 802.11 adapter.  If you have a wireless network you should be able to simply connect to the wireless network using the built-in tools within the operating system once the device drivers have been installed.

Comment: @dempap: Could you try to make clearer if you are trying to use the device as an access point or as a wireless adapter? Your last sentence sounds more like setting a static IP for the "wireless adapter", not the access point. What mode is the slider on the side of the device set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome manual, definitely!

Disclaimer:
This is somewhat speculative, which is okay regarding the provided manual i guess. :-) Also be sure you know how to undo your changes of settings before you change anything.

Make sure you have the USB end of the device connected to your computer. Connect the **wired network adapter** of your computer to the device using a LAN cable.

Change your **wired network adapter** settings as described in the "guide", they assume you connect with a wireless adapter which you don't have, but it seems you can use your regular network card to do so.
Once you have changed your adapter settings, point your browser at `192.168.1.254` and proceed with configuring the device to your needs from the web interface.

For clarification: I believe the device is using the USB only for power, not for the connection part. Thus you might not see it show up as a device on your computer.

I think that is the answer you are looking for. Not entirely sure though.

Comment: @dempap: can you do a `ping 192.168.1.254`?

Comment: After setting up an IP address along with subnet mask, URL address `192.168.1.254` worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where RTFM is painful!

Please make sure that you have the ethernet cable hooked up to your PC, or that you have connected your computer's wireless card to the SSID of the access point.

To access network connections to chane your IP address in windows 7:

Option 1: use the search box
I'm constantly amazed by how many Windows 7 and Vista users have no idea they can search right from the Start Menu. Click your Windows button (or hit the Windows Flag key on your keyboard) and type the word `connections`  in the search box. Wait a moment, and you'll see view network connections appear. Click it, and you'll be shown every network adapter.

Option 2: remember the magic words: `ncpa.cpl`. A .cpl file is a Control Panel applet in Windows -- which you can see sprawled out if you turn on classic view when you have the screen open. Typing ncpa.cpl into either the search box or run dialog and pressing enter will also get you to your connections in a hurry. You can also enter control netconnections... but that's so many more letters!